# Is it possible to change/update the company details for an Apple Developer Enterprise Program?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-developer-program

I have enrolled for Apple Developer Enterprise Program using the details of company ABC (Parent Company). Now there is a situation where we will need the Enterprise Program to have the details of company XYZ which is the sister concern of ABC. Do I have to enroll once again or Is it possible to update the company details?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't have to enroll again.
I've never had an exact case. But it shouldn't be something different.

Whenever the company's info needs to be updated, the agent should contact the Apple's support. Apple will ask to provide legal documents which acknowledge the existing of the company and that the person may represent it. That's it.

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: We went ahead and enrolled again with the details of the newer company.